# How does Matthews Correlation Coefficient define random predictions for binary classificattion?

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes

As stated in [Matthews, Brian W. "Comparison of the predicted and observed secondary structure of T4 phage lysozyme."](https://sci-hub.st/https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0005279575901099?via%3Dihub)

> C = 0 is expected for a prediction no better than random

I'm not sure how random is defined here. Is it weighted by the ratio of the target variables? Is it actual 50/50?

Comment: Yes, you intuition is correct (+1). Please see my answer below where I expand on this a bit further with a worked example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your intuition is correct; it is weighted by the ratio of the target variables.
For example, say we have 1000 points out of which 10% are of class B and 90%  of class A. We want to find our class B instances but we do a random classification based on proportions. i.e. we pick at random 100 of our 1000 points to be class B and the rest 900 to be of class A. Let's assume that class B is our positive class and class A our negative class; that would mean that we will have:

- $10\%$ * $100$ $B$ = $10$ $TP$
- $90\%$ * $900$ $A$ = $810$ $TN$
- $10\%$ * $900$ $A$ = $90$ $FP$
- $90\%$ * $100$ $B$ = $90$ $FN$

Focusing not only on the numerator of the Matthews correlation coefficient: $TP \times TN - FP \times FN$ that leads to to $10* 810 - 90 * 90= 0$. i.e. our classification is no better than random according this value. (in which case we knew it as by definition we picked 10% of our total sample at random to be of class B).